# Add a jQuerydatepicker on my page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

when i click on a textbox, i want to show a calender.
How To Add  JQuery `datepicker` on my text box in my page.
and How To Download it ?
Is this possible?

Comment: check this http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ try a google search before you ask..

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible just use the below source :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>

<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: @user3359375 you are all ways welcome to stakoverflow feel free to ask your doubts.. if working please accept it